# 3D vector iterate over sphere

Tags: c++, iteration, distance

I have a 3D vector and want to iterate over all neighbors that have a limited distance to a certain point (i.e. over a ball). I decided to use the P1 instead of the Euclidian Distance to make it a bit cleaner.
My approach looks like the following, but unfortunately does not give me all the neighbors.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>>> table;
int x = 5;
int y = 1;
int z = 3;
int MAX_X = 100;
int radius = 5;

for (int neighbor_x = x - radius; neighbor_x <  x + radius; ++neighbor_x) {
  for (int neighbor_y = y - (radius - neighbor_x); neighbor_y < y + radius; ++neighbor_y) {
    for (int neighbor_z = z - (radius - neighbor_x - neighbor_y); neighbor_z < z + radius; ++neighbor_z) {
      std::cout << table[neighbor_x][neighbor_y][neighbor_z] << "\n";
    }

  }
}
```

Where do I make a mistake in reasoning? Why doesn't it work that way?

Comment: Over a sphere or over a ball? For a sphere, you should have 2 loops and for z only 2 variants. 
Manhattan or P1? For Manhattan you do not need to modify lower bounds for y and z.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Thanks, I edited the question. I need to iterate over a ball and I'm using the absolute value distance (=P1)

Comment: You don't check for bounds. What are the sizes of the vectors? `z - (radius - neighbor_x - neighbor_y)` can become negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version with two checks.** You may simply check conditions inside. It is robust and you will be to change metrics.

```
  for (int neighbor_x = x - radius; neighbor_x <=  x + radius; ++neighbor_x) {
    for (int neighbor_y = y - radius; neighbor_y <= y + radius; ++neighbor_y) {
      for (int neighbor_z = z - radius; neighbor_z <= z + radius; ++neighbor_z) {
        if (std::abs(x - neighbor_x) + std::abs(y - neighbor_y) + std::abs(z - neighbor_z) > radius) continue;
        if (neighbor_x < 0 || neighbor_y < 0  || neighbor_z < 0 || neighbor_x >= table.size() || neighbor_y >= table[0].size() || neighbor_z >= table[0][0].size()) continue;
        std::cout << neighbor_x << " " <<  neighbor_y << " " << neighbor_z << "\n";
      }
    }
  }
```

**Version with one check.** If you want to reduce the number of iterations, you may modify bounds, but you should take not a value(position), but the absolute value of a step (size of the shift from the origin). It is easier to write using relative steps.

```
  for (int step_x = - radius; step_x <= radius; ++step_x) {
    for (int step_y = std::abs(step_x) - radius; step_y <= radius - std::abs(step_x); ++step_y) {
      for (int step_z = - radius + std::abs(step_x) + std::abs(step_y); step_z <= radius - std::abs(step_x) - std::abs(step_y); ++step_z) {
        if (step_x  + x < 0 || step_y  + y < 0  || step_z +  z < 0 || step_x  + x >= table.size() ||  || step_y + y >= table[0].size() || step_z +  z >= table[0][0].size()) continue;
        std::cout << step_x + x << " " <<  step_y + y  << " " << step_z + z << "\n";
      }
    }
  }
```

You can go further and fix bounds using max/min, so you do not need any checks inside. But I'm not sure it worth it.